# https request twitter

Tags: c#, twitter, https

I want to send an GET request at twitter.

```
String request = "GET /** / HTTPS/1.1\r\n" +
                             "Host: twitter.com\r\n" +
                             "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
```

I send the request in a byte[] with sockets and get the error:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it "

It only runs on http.
What's the difference between http and https?

Comment: just out of interest why not use a library like twitteriser or something to communicate with twitter, it has a good api that several people have wrapped for .net?

Comment: Because our teacher doesn't allow it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is that you do not connect http port (80) instead of https port (443).

BTW You can use [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) (or other nuget package) to connect to twitter

Comment: You don't encode your request. To do this corectly you have to use SSL Stream. There is an example on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx (look for TCPClient)

Comment: But the error is: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it "

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between http and https?

HTTPS connects to a different port, negotiates an SSL connection, then sends an HTTP request over the SSL connection.